# CardView returns padding for Android API 19, even when i set maxCardElevation 0

Tags: android, layout, dialog, android-cardview, cardview

I have a cardView in my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/google_scrim"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw">

  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/top_guideline"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="0dp"/>

  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:id="@+id/popover"
      style="@style/popover_style"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/popover_width"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/popover_bottom_margin"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/popover_side_margin"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/popover_side_margin"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/popover_top_guideline"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
      card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/popup_corner_radius"
      card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
      card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp">
  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and I see it has different size for Android API above 21 or below it.

I know it's because of the extra padding for shadow created for API below 21, but I cannot make the padding be 0 (like it does when I debug API 21)

I have tried to set cardElevation and macCardElevation to 0 but it didn't help.

Any idea?

[image]